# Where is the V3 airway mentioned on the ILS 34 approach plate for KPSM?

Tags: flight-planning, ifr-navigation

While drafting a simple flight plan for KBOS to KPSM, I noticed that the [ILS 34 Approach plate](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/2108/pdf/00678IL34.PDF) for KPSM mentioned that the procedure turn is "NA for arrivals at PSM VOR/DME on V3 northbound":

[image: Subset of ILS 23 approach plate]

What does "V3" mean in this context?  I assume it's a victor airway, but I don't see a V3 on the VFR map:

[image: VFR Map]

V3 doesn't seem to be a radial from the PSM VOR, since neither 003 or 030 radials intercept the approach course of 345.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We usually prefer to have each question asked separately, so you might want to ask your second question about filing in a new question.

Comment: Sure. Edited to remove 2nd question.  The answer to the 1st will imply an answer to the 2nd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V3 does indeed refer to the low-altitude Federal airway designated "V3" which is defined in [the 7400.11E](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1038054) (page E-1028) as:

> From Key West, FL; [many other VORs and intersections]; **Boston; INT Boston 014° and Pease, NH, 185° radials; Pease; INT Pease 004° and Augusta, ME, 233° radials; Augusta;** [several other VORs and intersections]; Presque Isle, ME; to Quebec, PQ, Canada. The airspace within R-2916, R-2934, R-2935, and within Canada is excluded.

But on the current version of the charts (as @mins says, you should look at the Low Enroute chart, not the VFR chart) V3 seems to end at BOS and does not appear again until PQI. From PQI, V3 exists westbound direct to YQB until intersecting the Canadian border (where it terminates at a point named LABRE). So what gives?

Look again at the document control page for the 7400.11E and click on the "[Amendments](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/airspace_amendments/)" link. It becomes apparent that a change numbered [20-AEA-10](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2021-04-13/html/2021-07529.htm) went into effect in April 2021 amending, among other airways, V3. The airway definition now reads:

> [yadda yadda yadda]; to Boston. From Presque Isle, ME; to Quebec, PQ, Canada. The airspace within R-2916, R-2934, R-2935, and within Canada is excluded.

So the ILS Runway 34 approach plate references an airway that no longer exists at that location. Perhaps you should bring this to the attention of the charts and procedures office by submitting an [Aeronautical Inquiry](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Aeronautical_Inquiries/).

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering where the airways were defined. I did wind up submitting an inquiry as per your suggestion and will update with their response here.

Comment: FAA replied: "The note can be disregarded and will be removed on a future amendment."  I assume they mean they are going to rollback 20-AEA-10 and V3 will be re-introduced around KPSM.

Comment: @Chris I would very much doubt that... more likely they will do just what they say, remove the note and leave it at that. (I'm not sure if those "Procedure NA" notes are there because of the sharp turn required or to prevent traffic conflicts.)